# Scroll element exactly as many pixels as finger moves (ios style gallery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

```
var maxTime = 100000, // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
maxDistance = 50,  // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the swipe
target = $('#gallery ul'),
startX = 0,
startTime = 0,
touch = "ontouchend" in document,
startEvent = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
moveEvent = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
endEvent = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';
target.bind(startEvent, function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // prevent image drag (Firefox)
  startTime = e.timeStamp;
  startX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX;
}).bind(moveEvent, function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var currentX = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
    currentDistance = (startX === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(currentX - startX),
    // allow if movement < 1 sec
  currentTime = e.timeStamp;
  if (startTime !== 0 && currentTime - startTime < maxTime && currentDistance > maxDistance) {
    if (currentX < startX) {
      galleryNext();
    }
    if (currentX > startX) {
      galleryPrev();
    }
    startTime = 0;
    startX = 0;
  }
}).bind(endEvent, function(e){
  startTime = 0;
  startX = 0;
});
```

This is a script I've modified so that it runs the function to switch to the next images in the scroll element. What I need it to do is operate as the iPhone gallery does, where the element scrolls with my finger as I move it, and upon release either goes to the next image or brings the current one back into view on the touchend event. I've tried switching functions between events and removing preventDefault to allow natural scrolling, and then trying to apply the functions but this allows the element to scroll continuously as it normally would, which is not what I want.

Anyone able to help? Thanks in advance.